# When booting why is my USB key recognised as a floppy disk

Tags: assembly, binary, usb, bootloader, bios

I wrote a small assembly bootloader simply printing Hello on the screen using BIOS interrupts. I wrote the binary to a USB key.

When I boot, the system recognizes my USB as a floppy disk.

Why is that? Normally when I install a OS on a key it doesn't recognize it as a floppy disk. Is there some kind of flag in the first sector to tell the BIOS that it is a usb key?

Comment: Usually there's a partition table; did you check it with fdisk after writing the MBR?  But yes possibly there's also some bytes *in* the legacy BIOS MBR itself that indicate something, IDK.

Comment: Where is that partition table located? Because I modified only the first 512 first bytes. And yes fdisk returns /dev/sdb for the device. Disklabel type: dos

Comment: @PeterCordes There' s a medium description byte somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

@Peter Cordes was right. The presence or not of a partition table indicates to the BIOS if the media is a USB drive.

Without the presence of a partition table (even one that's not in use), the BIOS recognizes the key as a floppy disk.

[image]

I found out about it when I partitioned the USB key using fdisk.

It is because I replaced everything on the MBR with zeroes after my booting code that the BIOS recognized the key as a floppy disk (since I overwrote the partition table).

In the picture you can see the bytes of the key before and after I partitioned the USB key. Now my BIOS recognizes the key as a USB key.